# Transform VA01 tcode to Fiori UI?

Tags: sap-fiori, sap-cloud-platform, s4hana

I am configuring the transaction VA01 "Create sales order" for S/4 HANA 1709.

Now, when I am clicking the button, it throws the error:

> VA01 is unknown

I changed the app type to url and put `"/sap/bc/gui/sap/its/webgui?~transaction=VA01&sap-client=100&sap-language=EN"` but it's throwing the same error. This tcode is running from back-end but how to execute it through the Fiori app from front-end?

1. From here on, remote connection VA01 can be run:

   [image]
2. Roles assigned:

   [image]
3. Target mapping:

   [image]
4. Role menu: from here, `VA01` can be executed succesfully.

   [image]

Comment: This document might be helpful for you [Step-by-step guide to enable Transactions in Fiori Launchpad using Application Descriptors in S/4HANA 1610 On-Premise](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/download/attachments/449910788/Final_Step-by-step%20guide%20to%20enable%20Transactions%20using%20Application%20Descriptors%20in%20S4HANA%201610%20On-Premise.pdf?api=v2)

Comment: Check you are pointing the service to a trusted remote alias (and not local)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are in a Hub Architecture. That is, you have a separate Gateway server and a Backend server. So your configurations are resulting in running VA01 in the Gateway server, where the transaction does not exist. So it is a valid error.

SO problem seems to be in mentioning the right system alias in the 'Target Mapping'(pointing to ECC) so that the transaction gets executed on ECC server, not on Gateway.

Comment: Thanks! I added the system alias in target mapping which is pointing to the backend HANA 1709 system but it is not working! Should I share some screenshots? PLease reply! I am stuck for 3 weeks now!

Comment: Any changes to Fiori configs would need clearing cache at SE38 -> /UI2/DELETE_CACHE. Yeah screenshots of the system alias definition can help.

Comment: @Tridwip: Are you using a RFC connection of type H? Also we had a bug, where we had to enter the RFC name and not the system alias for the H-RFC. You could try that...

Comment: I was putting wrong system alias. Now its working. Thank you all!